# How to cross-reference to Example

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, examples

In a journal article manuscript, suppose that we have an example:

**Question 1:** What are the alternatives for titling and numbering the examples instead of

```
  \textbf{Example 1.}
```

**Question 2:**
How to cross-reference to Example 1 in a figure or table caption? (I usually use `\cref` )

[image]

Comment: The most reliable is `\newtheorem{example}{Example}`, of which you can customise the layout.

Comment: Yes, that's good. Thanks. I defined `\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}` . But the texts of examples are and remarks are italic. How to do non-italic

Comment: Did you load `amsthm`?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it still doesn't work. So, I added `\normalfont` after `\begin{example}`

Comment: That's quite strange. Could  post a small, yet compete, code illustrating your problem?